# Does Amazon's S3 Permit you to set a whole bucket to RRS?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using S3. And, I realize that it provides for Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) which is substantially cheaper. Is there a way to set a whole bucket to RRS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set bucket as a RRS is not possible at present in Amazon S3. The RRS does set on Object Level.

**I am one of the developer of Bucket Explorer.** and You can set Bucket Default for the Bucket and then every new upload in that s3 Bucket will have RRS enabled on it. and for all existing S3 files you can set RRS Using Batch Operation.